# Plex Media Server cannot see sub folders.. Permissions issue?

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, file-server

I am trying to setup a RaspberryPi as a Plex Media Server.

The server is setup and running. I can access it via the web interface.

I want my media files in the directory `/mnt/sda/will/plex`.

This is the permissions of that directory:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/sda/will $ sudo ls -lstr
total 8
4 drwxrwxrwx 3 will root 4096 Dec 28 16:53  plex
4 drwxrwxrwx 2 will will 4096 Dec 28 16:53 'test folder'
```

My Plex server is using user `will`:

`pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/sda/will $ sudo nano /etc/default/plexmediaserver` with line `export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_USER=will`.

Neither folders `plex` or `test folder` can be see by Plex:

[image: plex cannot see sub-directory]

No media added to directory`/mnt/sda/will/` or either sub-directories is picked up by Plex.

This has all the hallmarks of a permissions issue but I can't see at all where they are incorrect.

It's might be worth noting that I can access the folders via networked drive using user `will`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the permissions on the folders at or above /mnt/sda/will.  All of those folders need to have r and x permission on them.  'x' means something different on folders than files.  You could probably solve the problem running the following commands:

```
sudo chmod a+rX /mnt
sudo chmod a+rX /mnt/sda
sudo chmod a+rX /mnt/sda/will
```

When running chmod +X (the X being capitalized) it will only apply the x permission to folders which makes it very useful when used recursively.